# installed node-squarespace-server, sqs command not found

Tags: node.js, server, squarespace

using https://github.com/kitajchuk/node-squarespace-server to develop a clients site locally, but I can't run the sqs command, it just tells me that the command is not found. I have node installed, can't find any other posts about this. Anyone have a solution or idea?